# Java and Javascript connectivity

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, class

I have a java class that gives a given set out outputs (e.g. the "Hello World" string). I also have a webpage that will need to call these outputs.

I'm struggling to be able to call the Java class from javascript. I suspect I'll need to use an ajax call but I haven't been able to do this yet. I'd prefer obviously to reduce reliance on third party tools or libraries if possible but including something like jQuery would be fine.

The connectivity is expected to be asynchronous and a physical delay is acceptable. Unfortunately most of the ajax examples I found restrict themselves just to javascript and don't go so far as calling an independent java class.

Advice/examples would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think you have to run a Java web or application server, like Tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/.

Comment: Yes I assume there will be a web server somewhere in the mix ;)